# Is it possible to see a list of deferred transactions

Tags: cleos, deferred-transactions

How can I access a list of deferred transactions on the chain? Is there a command in cleos for this and can it be used to filter for results from individual accounts?

Comment: Good question. I also need to know this. I assume it will show up in a block explorer; I will test this now.

Comment: Any idea about this, did you get any answers?

Comment: Actually yes, thanks for reminding me of the question!

Answer (score 4):

So I found a way to access deferred transactions using the following command:

```
curl NODE_HERE/v1/chain/get_scheduled_transactions --data '{"json":"true","limit":-1}'
```

after this, you would have to filter the results to get the deferred transaction that you want.